# Show that there exists $S$ such that $SA_1+A_2S+SB_2S+B_1=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A_1\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $A_2\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $B_1\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and $B_2\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Show that there exist $S\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that 
\begin{equation}
SA_1+A_2S+SB_2S+B_1=0.
\end{equation}

This is similar to algebraic Riccati equation. The nest question is to find $S$. Maybe we need condition on $A_1$ and $A_2$. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: the answer is trivially false when $n = 1$ and you choose the numbers so that the resulting quadratic has negative discriminant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, let $A_1 = A_2 = 0, B_2 = I$ and $B_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 0& -1\\0&0 \end{bmatrix},$ then the equation reads:
$$S^2 = -B_1$$
and one can easily show that this does not have a solution in the reals. So more restrictive conditions are needed.